# How can I debug JavaScript code with FireBug

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firebug

I know how to debug JavaScript code in FireBug that comes from a separate JS file but I don't know how to debug code that is in a page (razor view).  Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: Select the file that contains the code in the list of scripts...

Comment: I did try but I didn't succeed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same way you would normally do.

The in page js should be in the scripts list.

Answer (score 4):

Double click on the number of the line (on the left side) you want to debug and re-run your page.